# RDP connection An internal error has occurred for VM

Tags: remote-desktop

I had the following error message when login into a remote VM machine, But can RDP to other machines

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the console to login to the remote VM and restart the RDP services solved the issue.

Comment: I've just had this problem happen in the following way: the remote Windows machine in question actually went off the network. It could not be pinged, and some VirtualBox VMs running inside it also couldn't be reached.  When I went to the location, and tapped the keyboard, the login screen was there. When I logged in, networking was suddenly fine.  The VMs became reachable, and the host could surf the web and so on.  Trying to restart RDP service was hanging, so I rebooted the box, which was prudent in any case.